# Android gradle tasks really slow

Tags: android, performance, gradle, build

Note that this issue is only happening with this project on my Macbook pro 2013 with OSx el capitan.

Here are my grade.properties config:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

I run a simple command such as ./gradlew clean --debug and here is the point where it stucks for something like 10 minutes without memory or cpu usage:

```
11:27:10.337 [DEBUG] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformManager]  OutputStream: IntermediateStream{rootLocation=/Users/tiagorocha/Documents/git/golivephone/FamilyLiveApp/build/intermediates/transforms/jarMerging/androidTest/vfpt/debug, scopes=[PROJECT, PROJECT_LOCAL_DEPS, SUB_PROJECTS, SUB_PROJECTS_LOCAL_DEPS, EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES], contentTypes=[CLASSES], dependencies=[transformClassesWithJarMergingForVfptDebugAndroidTest]}
11:27:10.339 [DEBUG] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformManager] ADDED TRANSFORM(vfptDebugAndroidTest):
11:27:10.339 [DEBUG] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformManager]  Name: multidexlist
11:27:10.340 [DEBUG] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformManager]  Task: transformClassesWithMultidexlistForVfptDebugAndroidTest
11:27:10.340 [DEBUG] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformManager]  Ref'edStream: IntermediateStream{rootLocation=/Users/tiagorocha/Documents/git/golivephone/FamilyLiveApp/build/intermediates/transforms/jarMerging/androidTest/vfpt/debug, scopes=[PROJECT, PROJECT_LOCAL_DEPS, SUB_PROJECTS, SUB_PROJECTS_LOCAL_DEPS, EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES], contentTypes=[CLASSES], dependencies=[transformClassesWithJarMergingForVfptDebugAndroidTest]}
11:27:10.341 [DEBUG] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformManager] ADDED TRANSFORM(vfptDebugAndroidTest):
11:27:10.341 [DEBUG] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformManager]  Name: dex
11:27:10.341 [DEBUG] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformManager]  Task: transformClassesWithDexForVfptDebugAndroidTest
11:27:10.341 [DEBUG] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformManager]  InputStream: IntermediateStream{rootLocation=/Users/tiagorocha/Documents/git/golivephone/FamilyLiveApp/build/intermediates/transforms/jarMerging/androidTest/vfpt/debug, scopes=[PROJECT, PROJECT_LOCAL_DEPS, SUB_PROJECTS, SUB_PROJECTS_LOCAL_DEPS, EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES], contentTypes=[CLASSES], dependencies=[transformClassesWithJarMergingForVfptDebugAndroidTest]}
11:27:10.342 [DEBUG] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformManager]  OutputStream: IntermediateStream{rootLocation=/Users/tiagorocha/Documents/git/golivephone/FamilyLiveApp/build/intermediates/transforms/dex/androidTest/vfpt/debug, scopes=[PROJECT, PROJECT_LOCAL_DEPS, SUB_PROJECTS, SUB_PROJECTS_LOCAL_DEPS, EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES], contentTypes=[DEX], dependencies=[transformClassesWithDexForVfptDebugAndroidTest]}
*---> Takes forever here <---*
11:39:36.144 [QUIET] [system.out] [VersionsPlugin][VersionCode] = 3000500
11:39:36.168 [QUIET] [system.out] [VersionsPlugin][VersionName] = 3.0.5.x
11:39:36.210 [INFO] [org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor] Evaluating project ':libraries' using empty build file.
11:39:36.212 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor] Timing: Running the build script took 0.002 secs
11:39:36.212 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction] Selected primary task 'clean' from project :
11:39:36.213 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter] Timing: Creating the DAG took 0.0 secs
11:39:36.214 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] All projects evaluated.
11:39:36.214 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Tasks to be executed: [task ':FamilyLiveApp:clean', task ':libraries:DragSortListViewLib:clean', task ':libraries:LicenseManager:clean', task ':libraries:LocationLib:clean', task ':libraries:SC-Lib:clean', task ':libraries:moverlib:clean']
11:39:36.222 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.ParallelTaskPlanExecutor] Using 6 parallel executor threads
11:39:36.222 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :FamilyLiveApp:clean (Thread[Task worker,5,main]) started.
```

Total time: 13 mins 8.357 secs <--- for a clean without dependency downloads

From 11:27 to 11:39 it sits there idle without any memory or cpu usage. I've already tried several different settings without any success. In my Ubuntu machine this step takes virtually no time at all, and when cleaning the project it takes 10 seconds. I know the macbook pro is kinda outdated, and only has 4gb of ram, but it still makes no sense to idle like that.

EDIT: assemble --profile output:

```
Summary:
Description Duration
Total Build Time     15m14.21s
Startup                 1.912s
Settings and BuildSrc   0.701s
Loading Projects        0.070s
Configuring Projects    4.273s
Task Execution         1m5.99s

Gradle version           2.2.1
```

The time math seems a bit off :§

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found out the root cause of this issue.

In my buildTypes{} i had something like this:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    buildConfigField STRING_ARRAY, LOCATION_TRANSLATIONS, getSomething()
}
```

The getSomething() method was doing something that took quite a lot of time. Also it was being called for every build type and flavor combinations, a total of 15 call in this given case.

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    buildConfigField STRING_ARRAY, LOCATION_TRANSLATIONS, "{}"
}
```

I'm not sure why this is called in commands like clean, but that's what was happening.